# 2-3-4 trees node members

Tags: c++, data-structures, 2-3-4-tree

I would really appreciate a clarification in 2-3-4 trees... Suppose you have a tree defined like this:

```
class N234{  //node class
    public:
        int firstData, secondData, thirdData;
        N234 *firstChild,*secondChild,*thirdChild,*fourthChild,*parent;
};
```

class T234{  //tree with root node
    public:
        T234(){
            this->root->parent=NULL;
            this->root->firstChild=NULL;
            this->root->secondChild=NULL;
            this->root->thirdChild=NULL;
            this->root->fourthChild=NULL;
        }
    private:
        N234* root;
};

My question actually is how do i know whether a node is full (has all three values in it) when its variables(firstData, secondData, thirdData) have already some value in them as?

for example:
root: |4|  left child of root:|1,2| 
   right child of root |7,9|

Here root has one value (4). My question is how do we know that it actually has one value, since all of his other variables(secondData, thirdData) have some value in them (even if it is trash).. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we had only internal nodes to worry about, the simplest way would be to look at the child pointers:

If `thirdChild` is null, then the node is a 2-node, so it has only one meaningful value (`firstData`), and the rest (`secondData`, `thirdData`) contain junk.

If `thirdChild` is not null, but `fourthChild` is null, then it's a 3-node; the first two data variables contain meaningful values.

If all child pointers are non-null, then it's a 4-node.

The only problem with this approach is that it requires that a pointer be null iff it is actually *invalid* (e.g. the `thirdChild` of a 2-node) and not just unused. But not all valid child pointers will be in use (e.g. the `firstChild` of a 2-node that is a leaf).

So one solution is to **create a node which all invalid pointers point to, and which is not used in any other way.** In a sense, it acts as a second NULL, distinct from the ordinary one.

Note that it doesn't matter which kind of pointer (invalid, or valid-but-unused) points to NULL and which points to the phony node. (Also note that you could use any non-NULL value for the "second NULL", it wouldn't have to be the address of an actual node, but you'd have to be certain that it *could never become* the address of an actual node, and anyway it would make me nervous to use such an approach.)

Comment: so if i understand correctly the leaves will point to the phony one, while the rest invalid (thirdChild of a 2-node) will point to NULL? Or will all point to to the phony?

Comment: @CodeWiz94: If they all pointed to the phony, that would defeat the purpose of having a phony; there must be a testable *difference* between an invalid pointer and a valid-but unused one, so that one can tell the difference between a leaf 2-node and a leaf 3-node.

Comment: OK i see.. But my question still stands. Which nodes are considered invalid, and which valid-but-unused?

Comment: @CodeWiz94: ("Still stands"? That's the first time you've asked that question.) The `thirdChild` and `fourthChild` of a 2-node, and the `fourthChild` of a 3-node, are invalid. The valid `...Child` pointers of a leaf node are unused. Whether you consider the `parent` of the root invalid or valid-but-unused is arbitrary. So considering those two sets of pointers, invalid and valid-but-unused, all the pointers of one set should be null, and all the pointers of the other set should point to the phony node; as I said in the last paragraph of my Answer, the choice is arbitrary.

Comment: Yeah it was meant as a reference to the question of my first comment. My bad.. :) Anyway your last comment clarified everything for me.. Thank you so much for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

Your need to add a "total number of keys" member variable to your node class

```
class N234{  //node class
 public:

   N234(int x) : totalItems(1) { keys[0] = x; children[0] = 0; } 

   N234(int x, int y) : totalItems(2) {keys[0] = x; keys[1] = y; children[0] = 0;}

   N234(int x, int y, int z) : totalItems(3) { keys[0] = x; keys[1] = y; 
                      keys[2] = z; children[0] = 0; }

   bool isLeaf() { return child[0] == 0 ? true : false }
   bool isFourNode() { return totalItems == 4 : true : false}
  private:
   totalItems;
   int keys[3];
   N234 *children[4];
};
```

Then check if it is a 4-node.